# WPF Binding a Dynamically Added Control

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am adding a to the "Company" RibbonApplicationMenuItem in my RibbonWindow with the following code:

```
  var reset = DataContext as ICompanies;
  if (reset != null)
  {

    // ToDo: Create interface to populate the mymenutems
    var mymenuitems = new List<string>();
    foreach (var item in mymenuitems)
    {
      var newbutton = new Button { Margin = new Thickness(2), Content = item };
      MenuItem_Company.Items.Add(newbutton);
    }
  }
```

My XAML looks like this:

```
<ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu ToolTipTitle="Application Menu">
    <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenuItem 
        Header="Company"
        x:Name="MenuItem_Company"
        ImageSource="Images\LargeIcon.png">                     
    </ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenuItem>
</ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu>
```

How do I bind my new button in code when I add it to the MenuItem_Company? I need it to bind to a property in my datacontext.

Thanks,
Eroc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var newbutton = new Button { Margin = new Thickness(2), Content = item };
Binding b = new Binding();
b.Source = reset;
b.Path = new PropertyPath("SomePropertyOnDataContext");
newButton.SetBinding(Button.IsEnabledProperty, b);
```

Varying assumptions in the code...but it should give you an idea where to start...

Comment: apparently I am not getting the PropertyPath correct. I have created a method that is called "DoSomething" and dropped a messagebox in it to see if it is firing and it's never getting there. Any suggestions?

Comment: Look in your output window as UI components load, if the binding path is incorrect it will tell you so...which should give you the reason why. You are trying to bind to a method...or did you mean a property?